# C# WMI Remote File Access

Tags: c#, wmi

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
        connection.Username = "xxxxxx";
        connection.Password = "xxxxxx";
        connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:xxxxxx";

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(
            "\\\\xxxxxx\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
        scope.Connect();

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive='D:' WHERE Extension='txt'");


        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(queryObj["Name"].ToString());
            break;

        }

        Close();
    }
    catch (ManagementException err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured while querying for WMI data: "
            + err.Message);
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedErr)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection error " +
            "(user name or password might be incorrect): " +
            unauthorizedErr.Message);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to open the files in D Drive. Is this code right? This is not working. Button Click event gets called twice and it hangs. Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried to access the text files in D Drive. I'm printing the Name in Message Box @DieterMeemken